# Clustered data WITHOUT multilevel / GEE model?

Tags: bootstrap, generalized-estimating-equations, multilevel-analysis, sandwich

I have a data-set with around 700 observations from 12 centres. Although the clustering effect as tested in a random intercept model didn't seem significant, it seems more appropriate to use a multilevel / GEE model. But it may not be easy to do so as I want to test for multiple potential mediators. (to be specific, the model in my mind is a SEM without latent variables).

So my question is: is it theoretically advisable to fit the data in a single-level path model using ML (Huber sandwich estimator, or bootstrap SE)?

UPDATE:

Thanks for those helping out. Just a update for what I did yesterday. I tried the following models:

1. Single-level SEM in R (lavaan package)
2. Single-level SEM in MPlus
3. Two-level SEM in Mplus

(1) and (2) were fitted with ML (Huber / Bootstrap SE). (3) was fitted with Bayesian estimator as MLR did not converge. Basically all of the above gave me similar results but (1) and (2) gave me the chance to do multi-group analysis on top of the SEM and (3) seems to be more theoretically correct. I am not quite sure if the results from (1) and (2) can be trusted.

A quick literature search told me that Huber SE will give a correct SE even if the model is specified, but the parameters estimated may be biased. Under this situation, will (1) and (2) provide biased parameter estimates?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the sensitivity of SEM to detect mediating effects is far outweighed by the cluster level variability of multicentre studies, such as samples within schools, hospitals, or counties. Furthermore, any mediator is usually measurable as a covariate and can be discussed as such. And when that fails, there are way too many assumptions involved with SEM to make me feel confident that it can be used.

With 700 observations, it may be possible to adjust for fixed effects accounting for cluster level variability (11 indicator variables). This depends, of course, upon the number of remaining adjustment variables in the model. Too many will lead to collinearity issues. This is a fully parametric approach

Comment: Thanks Adam. Actually I tried the following models:
1. Single-level SEM in R (lavaan package)
2. Single-level SEM in MPlus 
3. Two-level SEM in Mplus

(1) and (2) were fitted with

Comment: @fred Why no mean modeling?

Answer (score 0):

GEEs generally require a fairly large number of clusters (e.g. a minimum of around 50), so you would be better off fitting the data in a mixed model with centre as a random effect.  Any potential mediators (assuming by this you mean covariates?) can then be included simply as fixed effects.

If you wish to fit this model in `R`, you could use the package `nlme` with the following syntax:

```
Mod <- lme( Y ~ mediator1 + mediator2, ~1|centre)
```

and obtain estimates of the effects of the mediators using summary(Mod).

Comment: Nick, mediators != covariates. The OP has a multivariate system, not just a single equation. Mediation is a term from causal effect modeling literature, and that the stuff that social scientists had to come up with on their own because statisticians did not bother helping them out.

Comment: Can you provide a citation suggesting that mixed models are not sensitive to small numbers of clusters in the same way GEE is? Remember, GEEs and mixed models estimate different parameters for non-linear links, so the model choice should be based upon the question one's trying to answer. Mixed models can be "marginalized" though, to obtain marginal effects.

Comment: @Nick, thanks but, as suggested by StrasK, I think the model you proposed may not answer to my hypothesis. I wish to know the direct and indirect effect of an exposure to the outcome through a few pathways.